# Why is my DbModelBuilder configuration ignored when mapping Entity from DbSet<T>.SqlQuery?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a `DbModel` configuration like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<WishlistLine>()
            .HasKey(w => w.PersistenceKey)
            .Property(w => w.PersistenceKey)
            .HasColumnName("WishlistLineId");
```

I have a query run via the following two methods:

```
public IEnumerable<WishlistLine> FetchWishlistLinesUsingLogonName(string logonName)
{
        return GetFromRawSql(@"
    SELECT wl.* FROM WishlistLines wl
    INNER JOIN Accounts a ON wl.AccountId = a.AccountId 
    LEFT JOIN Users u ON u.AccountId = a.AccountId
    WHERE u.LogonName = @p0", logonName);
}

protected IEnumerable<TEntity> GetFromRawSql(string sqlQuery, params object[] parameters)
{
    return _dbSet.SqlQuery(sqlQuery, parameters).ToList();
}
```

I can "save" `WishlistLines` into the database through EF without any problems. When I run this query though I get this error:

`The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'DataAccessLayer.DatabaseContext.WishlistLine'. A member of the type, 'PersistenceKey', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.`

I understood that using `DbSet<T>.SqlQuery()` would map the returned data to the entities but it seems to be ignoring the `DbModel` configurations. Judging (guessing) from the error message the wrong data reader is being used.

so:

A) am I doing anything wrong?

B) is there a way to make use of EF's `DbModel`-aware entity mapper?

Comment: You need to run your query in your DBContext. Btw, why you need a sql query to retrieve data? Why not just use Linq in you rDBContext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the column name mapping is ignored when you execute a raw SQL query. Here are two references: [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/adodotnetentityframework/thread/b7630f85-0ef0-4d06-8633-70faa2849583) pretty dissatisfying thread only for fun, but the following one with a serious answer from the EF team:

Quote from http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/233:

> The SqlQuery method is designed not to take any mapping into account,
>   including mapping that is applied using attributes. It simply matches
>   the column names from the results with property names in the object.
>   If the column names don't match you will need to use a column alias
>   (AS keyword in SQL Server) to rename the column in the results.
>
> We agree that it would be useful to have the option to make SqlQuery
>   honor Column attributes so we're keeping this issue open and putting
>   it on our backlog for future consideration.

So, the only workaround seems to be an explicit `AS` alias instead of a `*` in your SQL query that specifies your property name as a column alias:

```cs
return GetFromRawSql(@"
    SELECT wl.WishlistLineId AS PersistenceKey,
           wl.SomeOtherColumn AS SomeOtherProperty,
           ...
    ..."
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that is quite clean. In my model, I have public properties with the nice names I want to use, and private properties with the exact same name as in the database, and return the private value in the getter of the public ones, like this:

```
public class KeywordsStatistic
{
    public string Keyword { get { return lib_motcle; } }
    public int NumActions { get { return nbrActions; } }

    private string lib_motcle { get; set; }
    private int nbrActions { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, this would need to be modified if the values need to be updated, but the principles are the same...

HTH